# comparison ambiguity appears in javascript when I use `===` operator in strict mode, and can someone tell me that's why?

Tags: javascript, comparison, strict

The same operations come out different results, can someone tell me why.

```
"use strict"
console.log(+0 === -0) // true
+0 === -0              // false
```

*Execution result:*

[image: execution result]

Answer (score 4):

Nothing huge here, your code is being interpreted like below as there was no semicolon.

```
"use strict" +0 === -0
```

Use a semicolon,

```
"use strict";
+0 === -0
```

Strict mode has nothing to do with comparison. Have a look at the [abstract equality](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) algorithm. `+0` will always be equal to `-0`.

When it comes to your case, your code will be interpreted like this,

```
"use strict" console.log(+0 === -0) +0 === -0
```

So what is going on here,

- First `console.log()` would be evaluated first and `true` will be printed in the console.
- Now this part `undefined +0 === -0` will be evaluated
- `undefined + 0` is `NaN`, so `NaN === -0` will be `false`

Comment: It's interpreted as `console.log(...) + 0 === ...`, but yeah, same problem…